# Aligning text next to an image in CSS

Tags: css, alignment

How do I align this text so that it is vertically centered next to the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/frwC2/

Comment: [this is a good reference](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_vertical-align).  `vertical-align:middle` worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: middle` to the containing `<div>`s.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/frwC2/10/

Are you looking for something like this?